# Only one header and footer

Tags: php

I have a php code loop where I output the event details. The details belong to a each event, and in some case there could be just a single row and in others multiple rows. I would like to add a header and footer to each set of event details.

```
<header>...</header>
  <div>details</div>
  <div>details</div>
  <div>details</div>
<header>...</footer>
```

It's easy with the header, because I can check if it is the same event ID.

```
$eventID= '';

foreach($myEVENTS AS $e) {

     if ($eventID != $e->eventID) {

        echo '<header>...</header>';

        $eventID = $e->eventID;
     }

     echo '<div>details</div>';
}
```

However, with the footer is a bit more complicated. I cannot put it after each record -- it needs to go after all records for each event. At the same time, there could be multiple events. So the footer needs to go at the end of each event block. How do I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Make a block for each event and put the footer at the end of each block.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just don't know how to it. The footer has to go after the last details row.

Comment: You need to organize your data before looping through it.

Comment: My query returns a large object. Unfortunately each line of data contains event details as well. Instead of outputting each line with it's own header and footer I am truing to figure out a way to use one per each set of date for each event. I was hoping to use PHP solution.

Comment: You probably want to use `usort` to group the data according to your criteria. But from the sound of it you could be doing sorting in your database query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you wanted, but I will just suggest something

```
$eventID= '';

foreach($myEVENTS AS $e) {

     echo '<header>...</header>';

     foreach($e->details as $detail) {
          echo '<div>' . $detail . '</div>';
     }

     echo '<footer>...</footer>';
}
```

Was this what you wanted?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have all the data in details object.